# I have Python 3.3.2 installed, but cannot get Idle 3 to open

Tags: python-idle

I have mac OSX 10.7.5. I installed Python 3.3.2 via HomeBrew. I cannot open IDLE 3. When I type idle3 at the command prompt in Terminal I get:

```
-bash: idle3: command not found.
```

The program appears to start then close immediately. I have delved into the folders (`usr/local/` etc.)and found a terminal programme called `idle3.3` and various aliases but double clicking any of these produces nothing. Can anyone help?

Update: From another question I have found that I can get Idle 3 running by first opening Python 3 in the terminal and then typing `import idlelib.idle`. This seems hardly the right way of doing things, so I'm still baffled why I can't run Idle 3 by typing `idle3` at the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find where is your `IDLE`, then manually create `symlink`.
It works for me on Mac. I used the command:

```
ln -s "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/bin/idle3" /usr/local/bin/idle
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: I added one which works with Python 3 with:  `/usr/local/bin/idle3`. Now I can both use `idle` (for Python 2.7) and `idle3`

Comment: You could alternatively find and invoke it in one go with `$(which idle3)`

Answer (score 0):

There have been some recent issues with Brew and Python3.3.3, I can only imagine it a affected 3.3.2 as the symptoms are the same.  The installation was not creating symlinks and I could not get it to work either.

See : https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/26608

For now install 3.3.4 from https://www.python.org/downloads/

You can then run idle from :
    /usr/local/bin/idle3

If you need to use brew you'll have to wait for them to update the package but the bug has been Known for three months and 3.3.4 now out.  Maybe they are working on the version bump first.

Comment: Regarding your update. I believe that is because idlelib.idle is a library and it is listed in your PYTHONPATH where python looks for libraries. The symlink I mentioned would just link to this command directly.  This is what mine looks like : lrwxr-xr-x   1 username  admin        42 30 Apr 14:44 IDLE 3.app -> /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/IDLE 3.app

Answer (score 0):

I am on a Mac and I found that after a successful **`brew install python3`** there are already symlinks under `/usr/local/bin/:

- `/usr/local/bin/idle3` or
- `/usr/local/bin/idle3.7`

I use the latter.

Since I use mostly Python 3, I added this alias to ~/.profile:

```
alias py="python3"
```

Then `py --version` produces output that contains Python 3.7.4

Answer (score -2):

Install homebrew on Mac OS X then use it to install `Python 3` by running this code in the terminal:

```
brew install Python3
```

This will setup `idle3` and other dependency packages.